# Xpath to get main paragraph text omitting child nodes

Tags: xpath

I would like to match the main paragraph content of the following code, omitting the child nodes p, div, h3.

```
<div class="content">
    sunday, monday, tuesday,
    <br>
    <br>
    wednesday, thursday,
    <br>
    friday, saturday
    <div class ="tags">sunday</div>
    <h3>Days</h3>
    <p>....</p>
    <div class="style">monday to friday</div>
</div>
```

I tried Xpaths like `//div[@class="content"]/*[not(self::p)]` and `//div[@class="content"]/*[not(name()="p")]` , but none of them works. Then I tried `//div[@class="content"]/node()[not(div)]` and `//div[@class="content"]/node()[not(h3)]` it only matched the first text.

I need the text below

```
sunday, monday, tuesday,
<br>
<br>
wednesday, thursday,
<br>
friday, saturday
```

by omitting the children div class ="tags", h3, p, div class = style.

Comment: `//div[@class="content"]/text()` should return you required output

Comment: It will return only the first text, that is  "sunday, monday, tuesday,".

Comment: No. It should return you list of text nodes. Share the code you've tried and add tag for tool you use

Comment: That is what I tried first, it returned only the first text. When you use `//div[@class="content"]/text()` , it automatically get converted to `//div[@class="content"]/text() [1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
//div[@class="content"]/*[not(self::p) and not(self::h3) and not(self::div)]|//div[@class="content"]/text()
```

[**Demo**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22content%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20sunday%2C%20monday%2C%20tuesday%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20wednesday%2C%20thursday%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20friday%2C%20saturday%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%20%3D%22tags%22%3Esunday%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ch3%3EDays%3C%2Fh3%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3E....%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22style%22%3Emonday%20to%20friday%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E&=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22content%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20sunday%2C%20monday%2C%20tuesday%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20wednesday%2C%20thursday%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20friday%2C%20saturday%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%20%3D%22tags%22%3Esunday%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ch3%3EDays%3C%2Fh3%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3E....%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22style%22%3Emonday%20to%20friday%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E&extract=%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22content%22%5D%2F%0A*%5Bnot(self%3A%3Ap)%20and%20not(self%3A%3Ah3)%20and%20not(self%3A%3Adiv%5B%40class%3D%22style%22%5D)%0Aand%20not(self%3A%3Adiv%5B%40class%3D%22tags%22%5D)%5D%0A%7C%20%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22content%22%5D%2Ftext()&=%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22content%22%5D%2F%0A*%5Bnot(self%3A%3Ap)%20and%20not(self%3A%3Ah3)%20and%20not(self%3A%3Adiv%5B%40class%3D%22style%22%5D)%0Aand%20not(self%3A%3Adiv%5B%40class%3D%22tags%22%5D)%5D%0A%7C%20%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22content%22%5D%2Ftext()&input-format=html&printed-node-format=html&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto)

Explanation:

- `//div[@class="content"]` selecting the node in question
- `*[not(self::p) and not(self::h3) and not(self::div)]` omitting child elemnts: h3, p, div
  (or instead of any div `and not(self::div[@class="style"]) and not(self::div[@class="tags"])]` if you really need to filter div class ="tags" and div class = style).
- `|//div[@class="content"]/text()` then, join with the blank text()

Actually, this is a bit complicated. Maybe you are better off just selecting the text or do some DOM manipulation on the node.